# Configuring simplesamlphp for IIS instead of Apache (as a service provider)

Tags: php, authentication, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

A project I am working on has migrated from an Apache LAMP stack to and Azure enrivonrment, which is based on IIS. I'm trying to install  SAML2.0 support and am attempting to use simplesamlphp as I did on the previous set up.

However, working through the installation advice I'm running up against section 6 "congfiguring Apache" where it requires you to "Find the Apache configuration file for the virtual hosts where you want to run SimpleSAMLphp." (page is [here](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install#section_6)).

Is it possible to do the equivalent on IIS? I can't find any instructions about simplesamlphp. Skipping this step and doing everything else the installation / setup page of the app is unresponsive.

If simplesamlphp isn't a good option of IIS is there another package anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the equivalent on IIS? I can't find any
> instructions about simplesamlphp.

SimpleSamlPHP for IIS works great, but I couldn't find any good documentation either. Just do the following where you should be configuring Apache:

1. [Enable FastCGI in IIS](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis)
2. Create a virtual directory in IIS to the www-folder in the simplesamlphp folder.
3. Add read & execute permissions to the application pool running on the server

   Rightclick the new virtual directory in IIS -> edit permissions -> security -> edit -> add.
   Use the the computer as location, not the domain.
   Search for `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`, or replace DefaultAppPool with the application pool used in IIS.

Continue with [configuration of SimpleSamlPHP from adding baseurlpath to config.php](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install#section_6)

Good luck!